# Programmatic proofs for monad laws

Tags: haskell, types, monads, proof, formal-verification

In haskell, the users do not have to prove that their monads satisfy the [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad).

```
return a >>= k                  =  k a
m        >>= return             =  m
m        >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)  =  (m >>= k) >>= h
```

If I understand correctly, even if they want, there's no way for the compiler could read such a proof.

#### Questions

1. What technology is missing in haskell for there to be a way to implement such proof checkable by a compiler?
2. Which functional language supports such a functionality (i.e. can check if a claim-to-be monad satisfies the monad laws)?

Comment: I guess the short answer is "dependent types". You could look at how proofs can be written and checked in languages like Coq, Agda, Idris.

Comment: A monad law is no different from any other theorem you may want to prove to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, laws usually aren't *proven* in Haskell, but they may very well be *tested*. If you throw lots of random inputs to the expressions on both sides of the equation for your monad, and the result always comes out the same on both sides, that may not guarantee anything but it does make it quite likely that any law-violating behaviour would be caught. That is, provided you generate the inputs in a sufficiently representative way. [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) is usually pretty good at this.

If you do want to *prove* laws then, well, Haskell isn't really the right tool. You'd want the proof to be checked at compile time, but Haskell makes it rather difficult to express complicated values in the type level. If you do it at runtime instead, then first of all: no good if the deployed executable crashes because of a mistake. But more importantly, since Haskell isn't *total* you could “prove” any proposition by just giving `undefined` as the result – or some other ⊥ value, more typically this might be some subtle infinite loop.

The right tool is a *dependently* typed language. The most popular are [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) and [Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/), which resemble ML more than Haskell, and [Agda](https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php). These are primarily intended to be proof assistants rather that general programming languages which also allow you to formulate theorems; [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/) goes more in that direction.

All that said, modern Haskell is now also have somewhat capable of dependently-typed programming. The key tool is to have your functions as type families, and use [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) to get value-level standins to the type-level values, and then use either GADTs or constrained CPS to pass around the proofs.

It's still really awkward to use this to specify laws for a type class, but it can be used quite nicely to Curry-Howard-express concrete theorems. The [`singletons-base` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-base) contains a lot of standard functions in type-lifted form, thus suitable for proving stuff about. For example, here's how you could formulate that the list concatenation operator is associative:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, KindSignatures, PolyKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.List.Singletons

listConcatAssoc :: ∀ k l m ρ . Sing k -> Sing l -> Sing m
            -> (((k++l)++m ~ k++(l++m)) => ρ) -> ρ
listConcatAssoc SNil SNil SNil φ = φ
...
```

The complete proof will be quite annoying to write, but TBH proofs are annoying to write even in Coq, though that is specifically its job. Coq does make it a lot nicer to really express *typeclasses with laws* etc., though.

Comment: I heard but didn't know any of the langs you mentioned, and therefore I cannot judge the correctness of this answer. I may check this in the future. Thanks for providing me a(nother) nice reason to learn Lean :)